# Android twrp; Z5 compact; trying to find the recovery image to backup stock images

Tags: recovery-mode

I am Trying to backup the recovery image on my phone, before I want to try out twrp and custom rom options. I got adb and fastboot working and the phone is unlocked. I can boot into the TWRP image for the Z5 compact.

now I would expect with running /dev/block/platform/*/by-name/, I would be able to figure out the recovery block, but I get the following output:

```
[user@dine CustomAndroidRom]$ adb shell
~ # ls -l /dev/block/platform/soc.0/by-name/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            20 Mar  2 20:57 DDR -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p7
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 FOTAKernel -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p32
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            20 Mar  2 20:57 LTALabel -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p2
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            20 Mar  2 20:57 TA -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 aboot -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p27
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 alt_aboot -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p28
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 alt_hyp -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p12
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            20 Mar  2 20:57 alt_pmic -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p5
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 alt_rpm -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p26
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 alt_s1sbl -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p20
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 alt_sbl1 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p16
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 alt_sdi -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p22
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 alt_tz -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p24
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            20 Mar  2 20:57 apdp -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p8
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 apps_log -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p38
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 boot -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p29
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 cache -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p41
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 config -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p36
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 devinfo -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p35
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 diag -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p39
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 dpo -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p10
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 fsg -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p13
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 hyp -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p11
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 keystore -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p34
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            20 Mar  2 20:57 limits -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p6
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 misc -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p33
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            20 Mar  2 20:57 modem -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p3
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 modemst1 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p17
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 modemst2 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p18
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            20 Mar  2 20:57 msadp -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p9
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 oem -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p40
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 persist -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p31
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            20 Mar  2 20:57 pmic -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p4
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 rddata -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p37
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 rdimage -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p30
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 rpm -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p25
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 s1sbl -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p19
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 sbl1 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p15
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 sdi -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p21
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 ssd -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p14
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 system -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p43
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 tz -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p23
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Mar  2 20:57 userdata -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p42
```

which does not list the recovery drive, is there another name for it? Should I look for another way to find the recovery image?

Answer (score 0):

Xperias have a recovery-in-boot arrangement. The recovery should be within the kernel / boot .img. For which TWRP does not usually utilize.

Source [TWRP,](https://twrp.me/Devices/Sony/) pick any Xperia model your device is not officially supported.